# CodeIgniter doesn't work on Server

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I tried all variations of solution but still doesn't work.

I developed some script in my localhost(MAMP)

Then I copied the files and folders but codeIgniter says that `The page you requested was not found.`

How can I solve this problem ?

I tried :
- .htaccess modification:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /review/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|js|uploads|css|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

config modification:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://oursite.com/review/';

$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

Still doesn't work.

Please help me about this.

Kind Regards.

Comment: does it work without the .htaccess rules? and what is the url you are trying to access?

Comment: No it also doesn't work without .htaccess..

Comment: Did you set a default controller in routes.php?

Comment: Yes I set default controller..

Comment: Is your server a windows server perhaps? I had a problem like this with controller folders with a capital, (like Admin) where they were referenced without (like admin).

Comment: I checked all of them. Our server is LiteSpeed Linux server. I didn't reference nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get baseurl using code instead of typing in: Add these lines in config.

```
$root = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$root .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);

$config['base_url']    = "$root";
```

and also If your links do not seem to work, try one of the others:

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO'; // This works for most servers.
```

'AUTO'         Default - auto detects

'PATH_INFO'        Uses the PATH_INFO

'QUERY_STRING' Uses the QUERY_STRING

'REQUEST_URI'      Uses the REQUEST_URI

'ORIG_PATH_INFO'   Uses the ORIG_PATH_INFO

Comment: Then your problem may be with your server configuration. You have to allow .htaccess in server. For that find your server config file and AllowOverride. Then only the .htaccess file is accessed.

Comment: I use also wordpress and I didn't change nothing on my server. I guess it will work without configuration.

Comment: refer [manual](http://www.litespeedtech.com/docs/webserver/config/general#allowOverride) and check your's.

Answer (score 0):

Your setting is right , but in your .htaccess file , please replace everything by these :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Then write your own rules after it.

**Edit**

Also , i've used CI alot in my projects , then my config files go through this :

**config.php**

`$config['base_url']    = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';`

**routes.php**

`$route['default_controller'] = "main";`

it will work in all servers and locals with above `.htaccess` settings.

And notice that make your CI work in another dir/subdomain then check it again.

Comment: It didn't work. It doesn't related to htaccess I guess because I must see the view page with `index.php/controller/function` I cannot see.

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess vary depending on server. Hope it will help you:

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

You can also follow the following discussions:

https://www.linkedin.com/groups/Simple-Ticks-remove-indexphp-from-109912.S.5948862618142785540?trk=groups_items_see_more-0-b-ttl

And

https://www.linkedin.com/groups/Simple-Tricks-config-baseurl-in-109912.S.5948780645684621314?trk=groups_items_see_more-0-b-ttl

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

Htaccess:`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /review/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>`

config: `$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.oursite.com/review/';`
routes: `$route['default_controller'] = "realm";`

Comment: Have any space on your project folder name?